# Cannot request permissions report through API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

If we request a permissions report with the API, Azure DevOps responds with an error.

GET Request path: /_apis/permissionsreport?api-version=6.1-preview.1

Response:

message: "The requester XXX does not have permissions to perform this operation"

typeKey: AccessCheckException
errorCode: 0
eventId: 3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing this Rest API: [Permissions Report - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/permissionsreport/permissions%20report/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) in my side and found that if user is not a [member of the Project Collection Administrators group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/lookup-organization-owner-admin?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#show-members-of-the-project-collection-administrators-group), and then will encounter this issue.

Please contact one member to add you to this group, and then create a [PAT with full access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page), you could use this API.

Comment: Hi Stuart, Does my answer work if you are added to the Project Collection Administrators group? Please check it and kindly let me know the result. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm that adding the user to the Project Collection Administrators group enables them to use permissions reports.