# Cannot access Azure DevOps permissions report api without a "Full Access" PAT

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to call the apis/permissionsreport GET endpoint. As per the responses to

[Cannot request permissions report through API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66886904/cannot-request-permissions-report-through-api)

I'm utilizing a project collection administrator account. However, the AD level admins restricted the ability of everyone to create full access PATs. I tried to create a PAT token with all available scopes checked, but that was not sufficient to be able to call the endpoint successfully. I validated that on personal ADO instance I can create full access tokens on- a full access token worked in postman, an access token with all scopes selected did not. I get a 401 error with no message body in response.

Is there any way to call this API without a full access PAT token? Perhaps OAUTH?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the scope to **Custom defined** , try to only select **Read** access or **Read&Execute** access in the Build Scope, the PAT should be work fine as the following pictures set:

[Custom defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzfU4.png)

But yet not all paths are mapped to required scopes. A number of the public APIs are currently unassociated with a PAT scope, and can therefore only be used with a full scoped PAT.

So we recommend you to use OAuth to Authorize access to REST APIs.

For more information, you can refer to [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding the `Security (Read, write, and manage) -> Manage`
scope to my PAT was the solution